# I can not install pip3 on my Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, python, pip

I need to install pip3 on my ubuntu but if i run `sudo apt install python3-pip` I get following error:
[error installing pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iLXg.png)

If I try to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to solve the error, I get the followind message:
[error running --fix-broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBwEt.png)

Enyone know something I could do?

Comment: I allso tryed to stop the server but ... it sas "Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
"

Comment: Read your output: Your problem was there before you tried to install pip, and has nothing (directly) to do with pip. Your output tells you exactly what to do about the problem: 1) Stop your mysql server, 2) Then fix your package conflict. Then you can (optionally) resart mysql and install pip.

Comment: I tryed to stop the server but I get `Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded. `

Comment: Then THAT is what your Question should be about. How you stop something depends upon how you started it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I could not stop my mysql.server with `sudo apt remove --purge mysql-*` but the following command worked for me: `sudo systemctl disable mysql.service`.

So I removed mysql with `sudo apt remove --purge mysql-*` and the the installation of pip woked.

Comment: I'm happy you found a solution to your problem. I'm a bit concerned as to why it worked, this probably isn't a good answer for most cases. in the future you might try `sudo dpkg -a --configure` to resolve issues with dpkg package manager.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will keep it in mind